# Force close occurs while doing Fragment transaction to an Activity which is going to background

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

**Error message:**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)

```
 /**
 * replace current fragment with another
 *
 * @param currentFragment current fragment for replace
 * @param newFragment     new fragment to add
 * @param tag             name of the fragment
 * @param layoutId        container layout for place fragment
 */
public static void showFragment(Fragment currentFragment, Fragment newFragment, String tag, int layoutId) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = currentFragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    // check if the fragment is in back stack
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);
    if (fragmentPopped) {
        // fragment is pop from backStack
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(layoutId, newFragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

I have also changed code fragmentTransaction.commit(); to fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); and the same error occurred.

code used for invoking above fragment transaction,

```
FragmentUtils.showFragment(CustomersFragment.this
            , new StoreFragment()
            , "CustomersFragment"
            , R.id.fragmentHolderFrmLyt);
```

Comment: You cannot show a Fragment or dismiss a Fragment for that matter after onPause() is called. onSavedInstanceState is usually called after onPause() but before onStop(). What it boils down to is that you're are performing a fragment transaction in an illegal state.

Comment: Can you suggest alternative code for doing this..

Comment: Where are you calling showFragment(...) from?

Comment: I'm calling this fragment (StoreFragment)  from another fragment called CustomersFragment.

Comment: I meant the method. Are you calling it in a lifecycle method such as onPause() or onStop()?

Comment: I'm not calling that method in onPause() and onStop(), but the app crashes that going to background.

Comment: What method are you calling it from?

Comment: I'm calling showFragment() in onCreate() , then I suddenly press home button (app going to background), app crashed